How can I show files with non-empty tags/keywords in File Explorer in Win 11?
How can I show files with non-empty tags/keywords in File Explorer in Win 11? Using tags:* in the search box shows files with no tags (empty tag field) as well as those with a non-empty tag.

tag:<>[] seems to detect non-empty tags.
